# I deleted the .sbt directory in accident, How to make the sbt run again?

Tags: windows, scala, sbt

My system is windows 8, sbt version is 0.13.0, but I guess all window versions have similar problem.

I migrate my user profile form "something Dev" fold to "something" fold.

current the error is:

```
C:\activator>sbt
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\propertymode Dev\.sbt\boot\update.log (T
he system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:171)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:90)
    at xsbt.boot.Update.<init>(Update.scala:51)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.update(Launch.scala:279)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$jansiLoader$1.apply(Launch.scala:124)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.jansiLoader$2f324eef(Launch.scala:119)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.<init>(Launch.scala:96)
    at xsbt.boot.Launcher$.apply(Launch.scala:294)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:32)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:21)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Error during sbt execution: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\propertymode
Dev\.sbt\boot\update.log (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

my set is:

```
C:\Users\property>SET
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
AMDAPPSDKROOT=C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\
APPDATA=C:\Users\property\AppData\Roaming
CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME=PROPERTYMODE
ComSpec=C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO
GDAL_DATA=C:\PostgreSQL\9.3\gdal-data
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH=c:\python27\DLLs\geos_c.dll
HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH=\Users\property
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\property\AppData\Local
LOGONSERVER=\PROPERTYMODE
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=4
OnlineServices=Online Services
OS=Windows_NT
Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bi
n\x86;c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;c:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Clie
nt\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\
WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Compon
ents\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Pro
gram Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program File
s (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\W
iFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x
86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Prog
ram Files (x86)\Bitvise Tunnelier;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program File
s\nodejs\;C:\scala\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jd
k1.7.0_40\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS
\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\cygwin64\bin\;C:\activator\;C:\sbt\bin;C:\U
sers\property\AppData\Roaming\npm
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
PCBRAND=Pavilion
Platform=BNB
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
PROCESSOR_REVISION=3a09
ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
PROJ_LIB=%PROJ_LIB%
PROMPT=$P$G
PSModulePath=C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
SBT_HOME=C:\sbt\
SESSIONNAME=Console
SystemDrive=C:
SystemRoot=C:\WINDOWS
TEMP=C:\Users\property\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP=C:\Users\property\AppData\Local\Temp
USERDOMAIN=propertymode
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=propertymode
USERNAME=property
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\property
VBOX_INSTALL_PATH=C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\
windir=C:\WINDOWS
```

my %HOMEPATH% and %USERPROFILE% is:

```
C:\Users\property>echo %HOMEPATH%
\Users\property

C:\Users\property>echo %USERPROFILE%
C:\Users\property
```

I understand I can make the specification by setting the sbt.boot.directory parameter, but the default path do not change and any program on top of sbt like activator still apply the old path.

Comment: It should be recreated automatically. .sbt is not a part of sbt distribution - it is local configuration/storage. Check if you has permission to create this structure as user

Comment: I hope it's not some problem with the space in the path...

Comment: @ajozwik I already change my user profile directory from "propertymode Dev" to "property" I check my profile directory there is .sbt and if I delete it can recreated, but the sbt still use default directory "C:\User\propertymod Dev\.sbt\boot" as its boot directory. I do not know why

Comment: sbt by default uses `%HOMEPATH%` or `%USERPROFILE%`. I can not find which one. So check your system variables first.

Comment: @ajozwik just update my question the two default variable are correct with \Users\property and C:\User\property

Comment: `%USERPROFILE%` is used by default.   This is certainly an odd issue.  I think the actual error is getting supressed as well, as I know I had to code-ify it in to debug some startup issues in the past.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the problem on other user accounts on the same computer, or is the problem unique to this one account? Are you able to reproduce the problem on any other computer besides your own? We would like to help you, but it's hard.

Comment: You might need to look at the sbt source code and figure out what sbt does when the `sbt.boot.directory` parameter is not specified. It's an excellent clue that setting that parameter fixes it.

Comment: `sbt.boot.directory` isn't the only thing you have to change.  I think you're missing `sbt.ivy.home` and `ivy.home` as well.

What I would look for is where "mode Dev" is coming from on your environment or -D settings....

In any case, this is quite an odd issue we're seeing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find a way to fix that in my sbt directory, there is a configuration file sbtconfig.txt

add 2 line below:

```
-Dsbt.global.base=C:\users\[your user profile]\.sbt
-Dsbt.ivy.home=C:\Users\[your user profile]\.ivy2
```

and then the sbt and other sbt dependence will find the path